# SQL: Get Value of Column in table 1 from table 2

Tags: sql, select, join, left-join

```
Table 1(Validproduct):                 Table 2(Registredproduct):

ProductId  Name                         ID ProductId Quantity REGISTRATIONID              
1           chair                        1 2          10      1111
2           table                        2 2          11      2222        
3           desk
```

What I am looking for is below result for customer id 1111

```
Name  Quantity 
Table    10
Chair    0
Desk     0
```

I tried this but it only gives me product which exists in Registredproduct

```
SELECT vp.name as 'Product', rp.quantity as 'quantity'
       FROM Validproduct vp 
       Left JOIN RegistrationProduct rp on 
       vp.ValidproductID = rp.ValidproductID 
       WHERE REGISTRATIONID = 1111
    enter code here
```

and get this result

```
 Name  Quantity 
 Table    10
```

Comment: Left JOIN RegistrationProduct rp on 
       vp.ValidproductID = rp.ValidproductID AND rp.REGISTRATIONID = 1111

Comment: Change `where` to `AND` so the filter is applied before the join.  The where clause occurs after the join and eliminate the null records from the left join; in effect making the left join an INNER join.

Comment: Your where clause turns the outer join into an inner join. Include the condition in the on clause of the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause is applied after the joins, and filters rows in your result. You should move the condition to the join. Additionally, you may want to use a `coalesce` call to replace the null counts with zeroes:

```
SELECT    vp.name As Product, COALESCE(rp.quantity, 0) AS Quantity
FROM      Validproduct vp 
LEFT JOIN RegistrationProduct rp ON 
          vp.ValidproductID = rp.ValidproductID AND REGISTRATIONID = 1111
```

Comment: Actually this is what I need exactly along with "COALESCE(rp.quantity, 0). Thanks. It worked

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your query is that your `WHERE` clause turns your outer join into inner join by restricting `REGISTRATIONID` at the top level:

```
SELECT vp.name as 'Product', rp.quantity as 'quantity'
FROM Validproduct vp 
LEFT JOIN RegistrationProduct rp on vp.ValidproductID = rp.ValidproductID 
WHERE REGISTRATIONID = 1111 -- TOP LEVEL
```

This eliminates all results where a row with `REGISTRATIONID` does not exist, cutting the two last results that you wanted to get.

Moving it to the level of the join will remove the restriction:

```
SELECT
    vp.name as 'Product'
,   rp.quantity as 'quantity'
FROM Validproduct vp 
LEFT JOIN RegistrationProduct rp
       on vp.ValidproductID = rp.ValidproductID AND REGISTRATIONID = 1111
```

Now you will have `NULL` for quantity. Use null coalesce expression to produce zeros:

```
SELECT
    vp.name as 'Product'
,   COALESCE(rp.quantity, 0) as 'quantity'
FROM Validproduct vp 
LEFT JOIN RegistrationProduct rp
       on vp.ValidproductID = rp.ValidproductID AND REGISTRATIONID = 1111
```

Comment: Awesome Man. Worked like charm. :-)

Comment: @HoneyBadger It solved my problem but I am gonna go with Mureinik's answers because I realized I needed COALESCE(rp.quantity, 0) as well But Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering criteria applied to the in the where clause on a LEFT or right join must be from the table having all records.  Otherwise you eliminate those records with null values.

```
SELECT vp.name as 'Product', coalesce(rp.quantity,0) as 'quantity'
FROM Validproduct vp 
LEFT JOIN RegistrationProduct rp 
  on vp.ValidproductID = rp.ValidproductID 
 and REGISTRATIONID = 1111
```

Comment: Thanks boss. I got the solution

Answer (score 1):

When there is no matching record in the "right" table, a left join produces a joined record where all of the columns from the "right" table have NULL values; so your WHERE condition doesn't match them.

The easiest fix is to make the filter criteria part of the join condition.  In general this approach is easiest - you just move conditions from the `WHERE` to the join's `ON` clause.  Other options also might be less efficient (though I discourage worrying about that unless a performance problem is seen, as the DBMS should be better at optimizing than you or I).  The down side is that semantically the filter isn't *really* a join condition, so it's a bit hackish.

```
SELECT vp.name as 'Product', rp.quantity as 'quantity'
  FROM Validproduct vp 
       Left JOIN RegistrationProduct rp on 
         vp.ValidproductID = rp.ValidproductID 
        and REGISTRATIONID = 1111
```

Note that this generally won't work right if you want more than one REGISTRATION_ID because only one "unmatched" record will be generated for each validproduct record.  If that's an issue you may need something more involved.